# Highlight multiple words using Regex function

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have written this function that highlights a word, using ANSI escape colors. `\033[91m` is red and `\033[39m` is "reset".

```
def highlight(text, keyword):
    text = text.replace(keyword, "\033[91m" + keyword + "\033[39m")
    print text

highlight("This word is red.", "word")
```

[image]

**Q:** My problem is that the function can't handle multiple keywords to highlight (preferably one could enter any number of words into `keyword`). It's also not case insensitive. What could I do to remedy this?

---

I guess one option would be to use `re.sub` and perhaps separate keywords using `|` and ignorecase by `flags=re.I`. I have made various attempts, but I'm not getting there.

*This example correctly highlights the word, but unfortunately discards everything except the word itself. It also can't handle multiple words.*

```
def highlight(text, keyword):
    regex = "\033[91m" + re.escape(keyword) + "\033[39m"
    text = re.sub(text, regex, text, flags=re.I)
    print text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are replacing the *entire* `text`. Also, I think you should escape `keyword` in the *pattern*, not in the replacement! Try this:

```
def highlight_one(text, keyword):
    replacement = "\033[91m" + keyword + "\033[39m"
    text = re.sub(re.escape(keyword), replacement, text, flags=re.I)
    print text
```

If you want to highlight multiple keywords (passed as a list), you can indeed join them with `|` and then use `\1` to refer to the match in the replacement.

```
def highlight_many(text, keywords):
    replacement = "\033[91m" + "\\1" + "\033[39m"
    text = re.sub("(" + "|".join(map(re.escape, keywords)) + ")", replacement, text, flags=re.I)
    print text
```

If you want more control, you can also use a callable; the match is passed as a parameter.

```
def highlight_many(text, keywords):
    replacement = lambda match: "\033[91m" + match.group() + "\033[39m"
    text = re.sub("|".join(map(re.escape, keywords)), replacement, text, flags=re.I)
    print text
```

Comment: You should also be able to use .format to make this more python3 friendly, such as  replacement = "\033[91m{}\033[39m".format(keyword)  .  Note, python 2.5 and below do not have .format and 2.6 I believe requires you to use {0} instead of {} - RTFM for more